# Why does this code not compile correctly?

Tags: c++

I just found my code like this does not compile right? Is there any compiler-provided constructor here?

```
class A
  {

   private:   
      A(const A& n);

  };


int main()
{
        A a;
}
```

The error is 
test.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
test.cpp:11: note: candidates are: A::A(const A&)

I am using g++ under Ubuntu 8.04

Comment: Why are so many StackOverflow users challenged to use the <key>shift</key> in their question titles? (Title edited... )

Comment: @jjj: True, but most "question titles" are actually not titles at all so capitalizing the first letter of the first word should be appropriate. I believe either sentence or title style capitalization are appropriate, but if you're too lazy to do either, than I feel too lazy to answer the question.... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler will provide for you

1. the default constructor `A()` if and only if there are no user-defined constructors, and
2. the copy constructor `A(A const &)` unless you provide either of the four possible copy constructors `A(A cv &)`, where `cv` is any combination of `const` and `volatile`.

In your case, you've declared your own copy constructor, which means that the compiler will provide neither of the above.

The line `A a;` needs an accessible default constructor to compile.

Comment: wow...I thought default constructor will be provided.....because I just provided the copy constructor. I don't know default constructor and copy constructor are related.

Comment: To C++ both are forms of a constructor and a way to create objects for the corresponding type.

Comment: if I declare only an operator assignment, will the default constructor be declared implicitly?

Comment: They are related in that the copy constructor is (a special kind of) a constructor and providing your own constructor (copy or not) will suppress the automatic generation of the default constructor.

Comment: skydoor, yes, declaring the assignment operator will have no impact on the automatic generation of the default constructor.

Comment: Assignment is unrelated to object construction. In assignment say `a=b` both objects a and b are already constructed and "a" must now get a copy of b depending on the semantics of your application. So, yes if you only declare an assignment operator C++ will still declare a default constructor for you implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor you declared private in class A is a copy constructor.

Whenever you provide a parameterised constructor for a class C++ won't provide a default constructor ( one taking no arguments ). You have to explicitly define the default class constructor for your class.